# JQuery, non-greedy and working on non dom elements

Tags: jquery

I have some html getting returned via an Ajax call, lets assume its 10K in size. I need to look at the first 20 characters and get the content of a span in it

e.g. a document like this

```
var myDoc = "<span class=MyClass>text</span><div>...
```

Ideally I could so something like this

```
$("span.MyClass", myDoc, nonGreedy)
```

Which would mean look at myDoc rather than the dom, don't be greedy (in reg exp terms) but stop looking the moment you find the first instance

Is this possible? Can jQuery operate over random text rather than the dom?

I don't know how the jQuery internals work so I don't know if it evaluates the whole dom first and if non greedy is a concept that makes sense here?

I'll state the obvious, I can do this easily enough in plain javascript using indexOf, I want to know what jQuery can do.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can't do this "non-greedy" in the sense that it only parses part of the HTML string, it parses everything passed to it, but generally that's not an issue as you're working with variables kept in memory, and it's pretty fast.

The way to do it would be to create a DOM element, set the content of that element to the HTML gotten from the ajax call, and then find the first span element

```
var firstSpan = $('<div />', {html : myDoc}).find('span.MyClass:first');
```

Another option would be to cut of the string at the first 20 chars, something like `myDoc.substr(0,20)`, but there's no way to know if that gives you valid HTML, and if it doesn't you'll get a parse error from jQuery, so it's not a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks for that, for my own unique circumstances it sounds like substring is the way to as I can guarantee exactly where the section will be in the html.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing more about the {html : myDoc} section above, I'll play with it but I can't seem to search for it as of course 'html' is a pretty common word. Do you have a jQuery docs reference by any chance?

Comment: It's just a way to create a new element and set properties with an object, so it's equalent to doing `$('<div></div>').html(myDoc)`, here's the docs -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#creating-new-elements

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var span = $(myDoc.slice((myDoc.match(/<span class=MyClass>/)).index)).eq(0);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/xLrdxk93/